# Extract maximum and minimum value from loop

Tags: r

my data is :

```
x1=c(55,60,75,80)
x2=c(30,20,15,23)
x3=c(4,3,2,6)
x=data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
a=c(10,20,30)
b=c(25,10,15)
p=cbind(a,b)

for (i in 1:2) {
z=x-p[,i]
print(z) }


 x1  x2  x3
1 45  10 -26
2 40 -10  -7
3 45   5 -18
4 70   3 -24
  x1  x2  x3
1 30  20 -11
2 50   5 -22
3 60 -10  -8
4 55  13  -9
```

from z how to extract maximum value and minimum value  of all iteration of loop together {min(z), max(z)} ?? my result will be like this

```
min(z)=-26
max(z)=70
```

Comment: it is just example my aim is minimum value and maximum value  .

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
range(sapply(as.data.frame(p), "-", unlist(x)) * -1)
#[1] -26  70
```

Of course you can also you `min` or `max` instead of `range` which simply returns both.

With respect to your for-loop approach, you should note that you are overwriting `z` in each iteration of the loop so after the loop is done, it only holds the results of the last run.

If you want to do it in a for-loop, you have to create a variable to store the results in:

```
z <- vector("list", length = 2)
for (i in 1:2) {
    z[[i]]=x-p[,i]
}
> z
#[[1]]
#  x1  x2  x3
#1 45  10 -26
#2 40 -10  -7
#3 45   5 -18
#4 70   3 -24
#
#[[2]]
#  x1  x2  x3
#1 30  20 -11
#2 50   5 -22
#3 60 -10  -8
#4 55  13  -9
```

Then, you can `unlist` and use `range` or other functions..

```
range(unlist(z))
#[1] -26  70
```

Comment: docendo discimus    
I appreciate your answer but if I subtract x by this way          `z=abs(sweep(x, 2, p[,i],'-') ) `

Comment: @user5934339, then what? I don't understand your comment, please elaborate.

Comment: `for (i in 1:2) {
 z=abs(sweep(x, 2, p[,i],'-') )
 print(z)}`                                                                                                                      max=70 , min=0

Comment: @user5934339, that's still overwriting z. See my updated answer